# Add a randomly drawn substring to each occurrence of a word (efficiency, Python)

Tags: python, list, replace, nlp

I have a long string and want to add one of two randomly determined substrings to each occurrence of a specific word. Example: Randomly add either `'_1'` or `'_2'` to each occurrence of `'c'`:

```
s = 'a b c d c r'
to_add = ['_1', '_2']
```

Desired outcome:

```
a b c_2 d c_1 r
```

I have found several ways to do this. For instance:

```
#Method 1
import random
import numpy as np
s = 'a b c d c r'
to_add = ['_1', '_2']
s_new = ' '+s+' ' # Spaces needed because 'c' could be the first or last element
while ' c ' in s_new:
    s_new = s_new.replace(' c ', ' '+'c'+np.random.choice(to_add)+' ', 1)
s_new = s_new[1:-1]
```

Another one is this:

```
# Method 2
s_new = s.split(' ')
for n, i in enumerate(s_new):
    if i == 'c':
        subscript = np.random.choice(to_add)
        s_new[n] = 'c'+subscript
s_new = (' ').join(s_new)
```

However, I am working with a very large corpus and so efficiency is key. The reassignment in Method 1 is very slow. Iterating over all elements in Method 2 also seems unnecessarily slow. I am wondering whether there is a better approach. Here is something I am thinking about, but I am not sure whether this can be implemented efficiently:

```
n = s.count('c')
to_replace = [np.random.choice(to_add) for x in range(n)]
```

At this point, I'd need some way to sequentially replace `'c'` with the elements in `to_replace`.

Does anyone have an idea how to implement this or another thought on improving efficiency?

Edit: Just thought of another way:

```
# Method 3
s_new = s.split(' ')
indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(s_new) if x == 'c']
for ind in indices:
    s_new[ind] = 'c'+np.random.choice(to_add)
s_new = (' ').join(s_new)
```

However, they are all pretty much identical in speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more performant approach could be to:

- Start by counting the amount of times `c` appears
- Generate *k* random samples from `to_add`
- Replace each occurrence of `c` with an element of the above sequence

---

Here's one way using `re.sub`:

```
import re

c_counts = s.count('c')
replace_with = iter(random.choices(to_add, k=c_counts))
# ['_2', '_1']
re.sub(r'(c)', lambda _: 'c'+next(replace_with), s)
# 'a b c_2 d c_1 r'
```

---

Timings on a larger array:

```
def yatu(s, to_add):
    c_counts = s.count('c')
    replace_with = iter(random.choices(to_add, k=c_counts))
    out = re.sub(r'(c)', lambda _: 'c'+next(replace_with), s)

def op1(s, to_add):
    s_new = ' '+s+' ' # Spaces needed because 'c' could be the first or last element
    while ' c ' in s_new:
        s_new = s_new.replace(' c ', ' '+'c'+np.random.choice(to_add)+' ', 1)
    s_new = s_new[1:-1]

def op2(s, to_add):
    s_new = s.split(' ')
    for n, i in enumerate(s_new):
        if i == 'c':
            subscript = np.random.choice(to_add)
            s_new[n] = 'c'+subscript
    s_new = (' ').join(s_new)

def op3(s, to_add):
    s_new = s.split(' ')
    indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(s_new) if x == 'c']
    for ind in indices:
        s_new[ind] = 'c'+np.random.choice(to_add)
    s_new = (' ').join(s_new)
```

---

```
s_large = f'{s} '*10000

%timeit yatu(s_large, to_add)
# 12.7 ms ± 730 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%timeit op1(s_large, to_add)
# 2.64 s ± 19.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit op2(s_large, to_add)
# 218 ms ± 4.44 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit op3(s_large, to_add)
# 213 ms ± 4.89 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```